# Trying to finish adder need if statement to change carry

Tags: if-statement, vhdl

I have got an adder with inputs a and b in `std_logic_vector(data_width-1) downto 0` and out output of sum `std_logic_vector(data_width) downto 0`. I am trying to use an if statement to bypass the carry bit and add it to the sum

I just need help with the syntax the idea is if the carry's MSB is 1 the it adds 1 to the answer(`sum`)

```
architecture v1 of adding is
begin
adding : process (A, B) is
    variable CI :  std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH) downto 0);
    variable SUMMER :  std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH) downto 0);
begin   
            SUMMER := A xor B;
            CI := A and B;
            CI_msb <= CI(CI'left);
            if CI_msb =  '1' then
                SUMMER = SUMMER + 1;
            end if;
```

I am getting syntax errors regarding (`summer = summer + 1;`) I am not familiar enough to know what is needed.

Comment: Summer is a variable. Use `:=`. I did not check any of the rest of your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign a value to a variable you have to use `:=`, so the code becomes `SUMMER := SUMMER + 1;`.